# How does Windows decide whether to use Deflate or Deflate64 for zipping files?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, zip

I am observing issues when trying to unzip files from C#. These files were created with the built-in zip feature of Windows Explorer (in Windows 8.1 x64).

The issues are based on the fact that sometimes, Windows Explorer uses the `Deflate64` compression method for its zip files, rather than the `Deflate` method (where only the latter is supported by .NET's built-in classes).

**This question is not about the programming issues, but about the behaviour of Windows Explorer.**

How does Windows Explorer decide whether to use `Deflate` or `Deflate64`?

Is it related to uncompressed file size? I tried various combinations, and at least found a bunch of files amounting to roughly 1GB getting zipped with `Deflate`, and another bunch of files amounting to over 2GB getting zipped with `Deflate64`. Or does anything else (number of files, maybe even something less obvious such as compression levels) play into it?

Is this behaviour even consistent across "current" Windows versions?

Comment: [This Github comment](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/11264#issue-83332102) by a Microsoft employee seems to imply it's `Deflate` until the uncompressed file size is approximately 2GB (2 * 1024^3), after which point it switches to `Deflate64`.